# SQL Server Management Studio refuses to connect to LocalHost and is not in Services

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've used SQL Server Management Studio plenty of times connecting with the Server Name `localhost`, but today when I tried to use it, the Server Name field was randomly blank, when I typed in `localhost` and attempted to login, after a long wait I got this error message:

> Cannot connect to localhost
>
> Additional Information:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a conncetion to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2).
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I looked up fixes to this issue, and people say that I must go into and find SQL Server in services and start that service. I looked for that, and no such service exists for me.

Comment: If you have instace name, you should add it server name like this .\instancename

Comment: For checking sql server service status look for sql server configuration manager in your programs and than start your stopped sql server services from there

Comment: @Afshin That's part of the problem. In my Services, the only SQL Service that exists is "SQL Server VSS Writer".

Comment: Did you go to sql server configuration manager ?

Comment: are you sure you didn't accidentally uninstall SQL Server somehow?

Comment: I don't have sql server configuration manager. I just found out another way of logging into localhost, by using the Server Name "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB". I was previously told just using no instance name was fine. It works fine now.

Comment: To clarify, it seems like you could never actually connect to `localhost` right? only `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: Yes, only (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB worked.